# I am getting this error in my android studio "Plugin with id 'kotlin' not found." how do i resolve this?

Tags: android, android-studio

Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'kotlin' not found.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (211 ms)

this is the kind of error I am getting when my kotlin file in run
please help to resolve

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue:

**plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found**

One possible way to resolve it is, first, install the Kotlin plugin if it isn't installed.

```
File > Settings > Plugins > (install/enable the Kotlin plugin)
```

Then after the Kotlin plugin is installed, disable:

```
Tools > Kotlin > Enable migrations detection (experimental)  <-- UNCHECK THIS
```

Then:

```
Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin in Project > (choose "Android with Gradle") > (enable for all modules)
```

That resolved the issue for me.